$f(x)=\dfrac{x^{3}}{2}+1-x\int_0^x g(t)dt$ and $g(x)=x-\int_0^1 f(t)dt$. If minimum distance between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is $d$, then $\sqrt{2}d$ is
Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two differentiable function on $\mathbb R$ satisfying $f(x)=\dfrac{x^{3}}{2}+1-x\int_0^x g(t)dt$ and $g(x)=x-\int_0^1 f(t)dt$. If minimum distance between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is $d$, then $\sqrt{2}d$ is equal to
My Doubt: I found function $f(x)=\left(\dfrac{3}{2}x^2\right)+1$ and $g(x)=x-\dfrac{3}{2}$
Is this correct that $\min(f(x)-g(x))$ will give me minimum distance between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$? or should I use that minimum distance occurs along common normal of two curves

I think minimum of the difference is what you need.

@Vasili but why both methods give me diffrent answer?  which one is correct?

It depends on the definition. Usually distance between two single variable functions is vertical distance. Distance between two curves can be a different story.

so common normal method is correct one for this question?

The question does not mention curves or graphs so I think it is a minimal distance between points (i.e. vertical distance).

Shortest distance between the parabola and line is along the common normal;
$$f(x)=\frac{3}{2}x^2+1, g(x)=x-\frac{3}{2}$$
let $P(x_1,y_1)$ be the point on the parabola where the shortest distance to the line occurs
$f'(x)=3x$ and slope of line = 1 = $f'(x)|_{x=x_1}\implies x_1=\frac{1}{3}\implies y_1=\frac{7}{6}$
Therefore the shortest distance occurs from $P\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{7}{6}\right)$
Now perpendicular distance from $P$ to line will be $\boxed{d=\frac{3}{\sqrt2}}$
using $d=\frac{|ax_1+by_1+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$
Regarding $min(f(x)-g(x))$ will be $min\left(\frac{3}{2}x^2-x+\frac{3}{2}\right)=\frac{7}{3}$
You can get the above result by plotting the parabola/ first derivative test


My doubt was reagarding what should use for given question?

@mathophile ofc, the minimum of difference of both functions as we saw was a parabola on the real axis,  so we can find the minimum of an upward parabolic function by multiple methods, however coming to the minimum distance, that always occurs along the common normal to both curves and hence finding minimum of difference of both functions will not give you the minimum distance between both, hope that helps(note I have used really trivial terms and not any rigorous proof)
